# IE 11 browser not closing in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

When trying with IE11 driver. It does not close with `driver.Close()` and `driver.Quit`.

Below is my basic code for launching and closing.

```
//Declaring IE driver
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
//IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

//Navigate to test URL
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

//Close the browser
driver.Quit();
//driver.Close();
```

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Comment: No exception. The browser does not closes. I have to do it manually after the test finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a BUG in Selenium:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4288

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/65

You could manually kill all processes:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("IEDriverServer"))
{
    process.Kill();
}

foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

I know, it is an ugly workaround and it will close all Internet Explorer windows currently running but at least it will clean up resources if you need to run this automatically.

Comment: I am not sure but somehow it started working. Anyways thanks for the code.